# PHP elasticsearch partial match

Tags: php, mysql, elasticsearch

i want to search with elasticsearch and show out the result with php. i want to make partial match like it's in mysql for ex:

```
select * from table_name where title like '%abc%'
```

But my codes doesn`t work:

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'type' => 'my_type',
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'match' => [
                'title' => '.*abc.*'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: you need to tokenize the fields in a different way. (something ngram filters )
check this link
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/ngrams-compound-words.html

Comment: post your index setting, mappings for more clarified answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using 'match' instead of 'regex'

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'type' => 'my_type',
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'regexp' => [
                'title' => '.*abc.*'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```